# How to capture formatted output in order to convert to fewer lines in R

Tags: r, string

I'm using a package that outputs one line for each iteration. It does this twice, so at a minimum it's feeding out 200 lines of small output. Is there a way to capture this output, then using the content or even line numbers convert that to percent complete? Here's what it looks like now:

```
perm= 1
perm= 2
perm= 3
...
perm= 100

Computing delta table
1
2
3
...
100
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
Percent complete: 25%
Percent complete: 50%
Percent complete: 75%
Percent complete: 100%

Computing delta table
Percent complete: 25%
Percent complete: 50%
Percent complete: 75%
Percent complete: 100%
```

Comment: Is this output from `print`, `cat`, `message`, ...? Which function from which package are we talking about?

Comment: Package `samr`, it looks like they're using `cat` from the source code I can read. One of the functions is internal; so I can't see, but I assume `cat` as well.

Comment: You can use `capture.output` to capture output. However, since you want to change how the progress is reported you need to change the function itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. Never done something like this before, didn't know if it was possible to parse it as it's fed.